# How to use list item in table cells using html.?

Tags: html, list, html-table

How to use the ordered list in a table, in which each cell will define a list item. like
[image: This Picture].

There's no way to define the column first. So I tried to make something like [image: This]. (This is not what I need. I just tried something because I had no clue to do something like the first picture.)

With this Html code:

```html
    <table cellspacing="0" border="1">
        <ol type="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Heading 1</th>
                <td>
                    <li> data</li>
                </td> 
                <td>
                    <li> data</li>
                </td> 
                <td>
                    <li> data </li>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ol>

        <ul type="square">
            <tr>
                <th>Heading 2</th>
                <td>
                    <li> data</li>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <li> data</li>
                </td> 
                <td>
                    <li> data </li>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ul>

        <ol type="A">
            <tr>
                <th>Heading 3</th>
                <td>
                    <li> data</li>
                </td> 
                <td>
                    <li> data </li>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <li> data </li>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ol>
    </table>
```

Now I'm confused, how can I use `<li>` of an ordered or unordered list in each cell to make it as a list view?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Didn't get any clue to try.

Comment: From a semantic standpoint, it makes no sense to mix a list and a table in my eyes. Either you need a list, or you need a table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can put table cells in a list.  In each cell you have to put an ordered or unordered list, but that won't auto-number to the next row of the table.  You can either do that, and manually specify the next number, or make a table of 3 columns, first row is your headers, 2nd row has 3 columns each column is a list and use styles to place a horizontal line between each element, with length and spacing of the table cells so it looks like it closes the cell.  However, if you have some list elements of one line and some of two, this won't work.  I think you can't do what you want to do.  Sorry.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).